# How to get Element Submitting the form in Form Submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get Element(button/input) Submitting the form in Form Submit event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Instead you should bind an event handler to all `:submit` elements within the form, and do your work from there.

```
$(document).on('click', ':submit', function () {
    // this is the element that was clicked!
});
```